# show font awesome programmatically in TextView

Tags: java, android, font-awesome

I wanted to show a font icon (awesome) in TextView

```
new String(new char[] { 0xf3c5 ))
```

worked!

but

```
new String("0xf3c5".toCharArray())
```

did not work!

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(
                    str, 16)))
```

str has the unicode value like f001 .